# Python multiple variable optimization with recurrence definition

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I would like to minimize following function:

[image]

where

[image]

[image]

First phi is for i > 1, the second one for i = 1. I would like to minimize this function with respect to (omega, alpha, beta). I wanted to do it in scipy.optim but I am confused about this recurrent specification of the function phi.

Comment: Couldn't you precompute phi_1 = w / (1 - b) and add it to the sum starting with i = 2?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.